# draw multiple circles with array elements as text centered in them using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to draw multiple circles on a canvas with array elements centered in each of them & want to arrange them in a wheel-like structure. Later, I'll add line links to them. I've researched & found similar questions but even after following them, I'm not able to draw them on the canvas and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody please help me? Below is the entire HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >

    <canvas id="mindMap" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid red">
            <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>


</body>
</html>

<script type ="text/javascript">

var texts = [Pizza, Crust, Thick, Measurements, Size];

    var canvas = document.getElementById('mindMap');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var w = canvas.width/2;
    var h = canvas.height/2;
    var r = 20;

    //Draw user-entered words on canvas
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; ++i) {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#C0B7EE';  
        ctx.arc(w, h, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();

        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.font = '12px Arial';
        ct.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText(texts[i], w, h+3);

        w -= 50;
        h -= 50;    
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `texts` array probably should be filled with strings:

```
 var texts = ['Pizza', 'Crust', 'Thick', 'Measurements', 'Size'];
```

Also you need to add `ctx.beginPath()` before drawing a circle, and you had a type next to `ctx.textAlign`.

Take a look at the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DCU9YgQMFTVRS8WDNvCI).

Comment: Thanks a lot for resolving this. I also noticed that the text "Measurements" gets way out of the circle. Is there any way to center it within the circle?